# Azure Graph Api - Change Password does not work

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory

I have the following code in order to update the password profile on azure:

```
ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
            IUser toUpdate = await client.Users.GetByObjectId(user.ObjectId).ExecuteAsync();


            toUpdate.PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile()
            {
                ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = false,
                Password = password
            };

            toUpdate.UpdateAsync().Wait();
```

Apparently I am able to change the user password in Azure (Cloud) but it is not write back to local Active Directory. I have reviewed the settings in Azure Coennect and the PasswordWriteBack option is checked.

Comment: Are you using AAD Premium edition? Cause [Password Writeback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-passwords/#what-is-possible-with-azure-ad-password-reset) requires Azure AD Premium.

Comment: Thanks for you response and Yes I am using AAD Premium, Password reset also is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can enable and use the Password Writeback, you must make sure you complete the following prerequisites:

1. You have an Azure AD tenant with Azure AD Premium enabled
2. Password reset has been configured and enabled in your tenant

Please refer the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-passwords-getting-started#writeback-prerequisites) about the detail of PasswordWriteBack.

Comment: Azure AD Premium is enabled and Password reset as well. From the portal.office the users are able to change their password. But when we try to change using my app the password just changes in the cloud. The local AD still ask for the old password.

Comment: Did you mean that when the password change on the portal it writeback to local successfully? This issue occur when you change the password using the REST API?

Comment: Yes the issue occur just when I change the password using the API

Comment: Hi Guys please help me do you have other ideas?

Comment: @HenryGarcia I am trying to build the environment to confirm this issue. It may take sometime, I would come back if I have any update.

Comment: @HenryGarcia I am also able to reproduce this issue too. If you want the password also be write back after when using the Azure Graph REST to change the password or any ideas about Azure, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback). I am also trying to report this issue.

Comment: Thanks Fei Xue please let me know if you have any response. I already report this issue

Comment: @HenryGarcia There are moderators in the Azure feedback forum would review the feedback and consider change the Azure's feature to make it better based on the votes of feedback. And I will be back if I also have any update about this feature.